# royalty free embedded processor

Tags: fpga, embedded, xilinx, processor, spartan

I got into FPGA design last year for a project, and had some success with a Xilinx Spartan 6 dev board using ISE. I could do everything with this low cost board and ISE 14, which is free. I needed an embedded processor and used the excellent PicoBlaze - again thanks to great documentation this all worked very well and the project is currently in daily use.

Like many successful projects I can see things growing in future. I still have a fair amount of capacity on the FPGA, but the issue with PicoBlaze really is lack of a C compiler. I would like to find another processor that is very low cost or free, but for which I can build with gcc or whatever.

I had a look around opencores and some interesting things there - but a bit hard to tell what is actively maintained and has a user base. Can anyone recommend free/low cost embedded processor(s) that work well and are reasonably well documented?

Comment: I think ARM recently made some soft-cores free.

Comment: @VoltageSpike not quite true: https://opencores.org/projects?expanded=Processor

Comment: it looks like a comment is missing? VoltageSpike?

Comment: I remember we were willing to pay $1m for the HC07 core until funding pulled the plug after 7 years.

Comment: there are a number of risc-v, and mips implementations out there, cost depends on if it is commercial or not, a good, well tested one is likely going to be not free for commercial use.  amber and mpx on opencores are good an arm 2/3 (acorn days before the armv4/arm7) which has gcc support mpx being a mips with gcc support and the risc-vs have gcc support.  the lm32, and some others as well.

Comment: or you could just use the microblaze and the gnu toolchain...

Comment: obviously work backward from what gnu binutils/gcc supports to what cores you can find.  there are llvm/gcc maintained backends that are not part of the main gnu sources too but within the ones that are supported by the mainline gnu sources there are plenty of open source cores that have been fpga or asic tested.

Comment: @old_timer sounds lik a good approach, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the likes of RiscV, there is OpenRISC ( https://openrisc.io/ )

> a free and open RISC instruction set architecture with DSP features
>
> a set of free, open source implementations of the architecture
>
> a complete set of free, open source software development tools,
>   libraries, operating systems and applications
>
> a variety of system-on-chip and system simulators

The or1200 implementation is done is verilog and is released under the LGPL license

https://github.com/openrisc/or1200

mor1kx is written in verilog and released under the OHLD license

https://github.com/openrisc/mor1kx

Answer (score 2):

I have heard a lot of good stuff about vexriscv. In general, there is a lot of work around the riscv instruction set, in terms of compilers, soft processors, and all sorts of ASIC implementations.

Answer (score 1):

The Hennessy & Patterson textbook now covers the RISCV architecture.  Tons of academic papers on a wide range of RISCV implementations (including FPGA).  Also there is a RISCV consortium consisting of multiple very large companies.  So that open source architecture is well documented and likely to be well supported by software for a very long time.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the [Instant Soc RISC-V](https://www.fpga-cores.com/instant-soc/) in a couple of projects now. It really works great. It build an optimized RISC-V core and all around that based on your C++ code. It uses gcc and a compiler that builds the HDL.